# A slow scroll (parallax) background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a background that I would like to Parallax scroll (slow scroll) as the visitor scrolls up and down the page.

The background image is 1200px in height (800px in width) and I want the scroll speed to adjust based on the page content (Document) size. In other words I want the visitor to be able to see (eventually) the full background image as they scroll down seeing the bottom of the image when they hit the footer.

I've tried various different methods to no avail, the current js code i have is:

```
function calcParallax(tileheight, speedratio, scrollposition) {
return ((tileheight) - (Math.floor(scrollposition / speedratio) % (tileheight+1)));
}

window.onload = function() {

window.onscroll = function() {
var posY = (document.documentElement.scrollTop) ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset;

var ground = document.getElementById('bg');
var groundparallax = calcParallax(53, 8, posY);
ground.style.backgroundPosition = "0 " + groundparallax + "px"; 

}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="bg" class="movable" >
...all content code...
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
 #bg {
background:url("../images/cave-background.jpg") no-repeat fixed 50% 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Currently the JS code does not even work. It does not even move the bg image...

Insight would be great!

Comment: There seems to be a good tutorial on this at http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/simple-parallax-scrolling-technique/

Comment: Excellent! Please post your solution as an answer to your own question so others who have the same problem can also have a solution.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Vertical scrolling parallax background effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7521292/vertical-scrolling-parallax-background-effect)

Comment: Take a look on this project [Skrollr](http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/). Regards.

Comment: You shouldn't use the onscroll event for this if you care about performance. Always use a timeout and pipe your logic through requestanimationframe.